Transformation of Killing spinors under vielbein redefinitions
I presume the explicit form a Killing spinor depends on the chosen vielbein, as it appears explicitly in the Killing spinor equation. Therefore, given a vielbein redefinition $e_\mu{}^a\mapsto R^a{}_b e_\mu{}^b$, how do the Killing spinors transform?

In the context of a vielbein redefinition $e_\mu{}^a\mapsto R^a{}_b e_\mu{}^b$, where $\ R^a{}_b$ is a Lorentz transformation matrix, the transformation of Killing spinors can be derived by considering how the spin connection and supersymmetry variations transform under the vielbein redefinition.
Let's denote the original Killing spinor as   and the transformed Killing spinor as ′. The transformation law for the spin connection $\ ^{ab}{ }_\mu{ }$ under the vielbein redefinition is given by:
$$\ ^{ab}{ }_\mu{ }\mapsto R^a{}_c R^b{}_d ^{cd}{ }_\mu{ } + R^a{}_c  ∂ { }_\mu{ } R^{cb}$$
The variation of the Killing spinor equation under this vielbein redefinition can then be obtained by considering how the spin connection transforms in the supersymmetry variations. For simplicity, let's focus on the variations of the gravitino field $\ {}_\mu $ under supersymmetry transformations generated by the Killing spinor .
The supersymmetry variation of the gravitino field is given by:
$$\  _ {}_\mu = \ { } _\mu + {\text{terms involving other fields}},$$
where $\ { } _\mu$ is the covariant derivative that involves the spin connection $\ ^{ab}{ }_\mu{ }$.
Under the vielbein redefinition, the covariant derivative $\ { } _\mu$ transforms as:
$$\ { } _\mu \mapsto R^a{ }_b  { } _\mu  + R^a{ }_b ∂ {}_\mu{ } $$
where the first term involves the original spin connection and the second term arises from the transformation of the partial derivative.
Therefore, the transformed supersymmetry variation of the gravitino field $\ {}_\mu $
becomes:
$$\  _’ {}_\mu = \ R^a{}_b { } _\mu + R^a{}_b  ∂ {}_\mu{ }  + {\text{terms involving other fields}}.$$
Comparing this with the original supersymmetry variation $\  _ {}_\mu$ , we can identify the transformation law for the Killing spinor  as:
$$′=\ R^a{}_b .$$
In other words, under a vielbein redefinition, the Killing spinor transforms as a Lorentz vector under Lorentz transformations given by the matrix $\ R^a{}_b$.
This transformation law ensures that the supersymmetry algebra remains consistent under the redefinition of the vielbein.

Thanks! Just to make sure I understand this correctly. The matrix R carries to flat indices (a and b). The Killing spinor carries a spinor index (say alpha). By $R^a{}b_\epsilon$, do you literally mean matrix multiplication of a spinor written as a vector? So e.g. taking the same matrix R but giving it spinor indices instead, $R^\alpha{}_\beta\epsilon^\beta$?

@user984949 Briefly: The transformation of the Killing spinor under the vielbein redefinition involves a Lorentz transformation acting on the spinor index of the Killing spinor, not a matrix multiplication of the Killing spinor with the Lorentz transformation matrix. OK?
